# My web page is getting cut off and won't scroll on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

My web page won't scroll on mobile devices. It works if you resize the window on desktop, but if you view the page on an actual mobile device then there is no ability to scroll. This is causing only half of the page's content to be visible.

I've tried setting the body height to 100%.

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0, box-sizing: border-box;}


.news-module {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
}

.news-sub-module {
    width: 70vw;
    height: auto;
    margin: 2vw 5vw 3vw 5vw; 
    padding: 4vw;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.news-sub-module:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
}

.header-style-one {
    width: 100%;
}

.news-more {
    float: left;
    margin: 1vw 0 0 0;
}
```

```
<div class="news-module">

  <div class="news-sub-module">
    <div class="news-date">
      06.12.2019 </div>
    <div class="header-style-one">
      <a href="#">Meet Italy’s Most Passionate Tomato Farmer</a>
    </div>
    <div class="news-description">
      <a href="#">August in Italy: businesses are closed, cities have emptied out, towns are deserted—everyone is at the beach. Everyone, that is, except for tomato farmers in the Campania region, Italy’s tomato capital. Here, in late summer, trucks loaded with the vibrant, just-harvested fruits crowd tiny, one-lane streets...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="news-more">
      <a href="#">→ Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="news-sub-module">
    <div class="news-date">
      06.11.2019</div>
    <div class="header-style-one">
      <a href="#">Q+A with Winemaker Steve Matthiasson</a>
    </div>
    <div class="news-description">
      <a href="#">Steve Matthiasson was perhaps the most in-demand viticulturist in Napa when he and his wife, Jill, decided to start their own wine label. We caught up with Steve in the middle of this year’s grape harvest to talk about one of his favorite subjects: gathering friends to eat, drink and be merry...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="news-more">
      <a href="#">→ Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="news-sub-module">
    <div class="news-date">
      05.15.2019 </div>
    <div class="header-style-one">
      <a href="#">Spring’s Most Sensitive, and Bountiful, Vegetable</a>
    </div>
    <div class="news-description">
      <a href="#">“People say gambling came to New Jersey with the casinos,” laughs Tom Sheppard of Sheppard Farms in Cumberland County, New Jersey. “But gambling came with the first farmers. Out there in the field, mother nature can do all kinds of things to you.”...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="news-more">
      <a href="#">→ Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="news-sub-module">
    <div class="news-date">
      05.10.2019 </div>
    <div class="header-style-one">
      <a href="#">Can an American Parmesan Dethrone the King of Cheeses?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="news-description">
      <a href="#">Parmesan cheese is at the heart of Italian cuisine, and the greatest of all of Parmesans is Parmigiano Reggiano. So when you’re looking for a cheese to grate over a saucy tangle of pasta, there is no substitute. The Schuman family believes they can change all that...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="news-more">
      <a href="#">→ Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I want the ability to scroll on mobile instead of having the content getting cut off.

Comment: Are you using any JS libraries? Does your console show any errors?

Comment: Nope, no Javascript. These errors popped up when I viewed the console: (1) "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received."
(2) "Info: The current domain is not authorized for OAuth operations. This will prevent signInWithPopup, signInWithRedirect, linkWithPopup and linkWithRedirect from working. Add your domain (codepen.io) to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab."

Comment: Hi. Tried your code. Works for me just fine. 
Are you sure it's all related CSS?

Comment: Hi, I just tested the HTML and CSS above on my iPhone and I'm unable to scroll. Did you test it on a mobile device?

Comment: Why are you getting a `codepen.io` OAuth error?

Comment: The code is hosted on codepen

Comment: Have you tried putting this code not in codepen and testing it?